# adding a textbox on selecting particular option from dropdown

Tags: jquery

```
<td>
    <select id="sub_name_id">
        <option value="1">CHEMISTRY</option>
        <option value="2">ENGLISH</option>
        <option value="3">MATHS</option>
        <option value="4">PHYSICS</option>
        <option value="5">ADD NEW SUB</option>
    </select><input type="text" id="txt1" style="display:none;">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="obtainedmarks1" id="obtained_marks">
    <input type="text" class="totalmarks1" id="total_marks" value="100" read only>
    <input type="button" class="add_button" value="+" >
</td>
```

I have a drop down list with a bunch of subjects.

When I click on `+` Button the selected subject from the drop down should be copied to the text box(not mentioned in the code).

Also When I select `ADD NEW SUBJECT` option the text box with `id="txt1"` should appear and then I can add my own subject by clicking on the button.

Also while adding a NEW subject, if its already added then alert should appear saying subject already added.

Thanks..

Comment: where is the button for `Also while adding a NEW subject`?

Comment: If you can arbitrarily add any subjects you like then the value field becomes irrelevant.  If you explain what you're trying to achieve, rather than just ask 1 tiny part of it, then we can offer more relevant help.  Otherwise, we're just answering the first of many questions which will arise when you get this fixed and then say, "Oh...."

Comment: its the same button with same "+" button..the textboxes are added dynamically whenever i click the button

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#add_button').click(function(){

var selectedText= $('#sub_name_id option[selected]').text();
if(selectedText==='ADD NEW SUB'){
  $('#txt1').show();
}
$('#targetTextBox').val(selectedText);
});
```

Comment: thnks..and bt what about the alert thing..wht should i do for that

Comment: @user2849338, Where is the button for that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use following js and making some change in your html codes look like

**HTML**

```
<select id="sub_name_id">
    <option value="1">CHEMISTRY</option>
    <option value="2">ENGLISH</option>
    <option value="3">MATHS</option>
    <option value="4">PHYSICS</option>
    <option value="5">ADD NEW SUB</option>
</select>    

<input type="text" class="obtainedmarks1" id="obtained_marks">
<input type="text" class="totalmarks1" id="total_marks" value="100" read only>    
    <input type="button" id="add_button" value="+">
```

**JS**

> var container = document.getElementById('container');
>   document.getElementById('add_button').onclick = function () {     var
>   input = document.createElement('input'),
>         div = document.createElement('div');   input.type = "text";    div.appendChild(input);    container.appendChild(div);          };

Check Out This [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arun_/5aEZs/1/)